# If 2 out of 6 Machines are Defective, and 3 were selected randomly , What is the Probability Distribution of the number of Defectives?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Even more generally :

If **n** objects are divided to **m** alike and **k** alike , we select **x** amount randomly , then to find how probable is it that **y** objects from **x** are **m** , using some trial and error I managed to find this complicated formula :
$$P_{X}(y)=\frac{{x \choose y}(_{m}P_{y}) (_{k}P_{x-y})}{_{n}P_{x}}$$
But then it turned out that there is an easier formula with Combinations which is actually exactly equal to the previous one
$$P_{X}(y)=\frac{{m \choose y}{k \choose x-y}}{n \choose x}$$
I can't understand how any of them can be shown mathematically or why do they have the same meaning.

Comment: $^mP_y = \big(\frac{m}{y}\big)$, $^kP_{x-y} = \big(\frac{k}{x-y}\big)$ and $^nP_x = \big(\frac{n}{x}\big)$. I believe that when you have $\big(^x_y\big)$ you just use the combinations formula. Ideally if you plug in the values you would get the same result. Permutations/combinations isn't my strongpoint so take whatever i'm saying with a pinch of salt until someone more experienced explains.

Comment: They have the same meaning except they use different notations. Like writing $1 \times 1$ which is the same as $1(1)$.

Comment: @Ajay ok , but how do you come up with any of them in the first place

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This is the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig aha , I get it now ty. that's why this seemingly unrelated question was in my textbook lol.

Answer (score 2):

To help you understand the second formula consider this example.

Suppose a bag contains 8 Red and 4 Blue balls.
3 balls are chosen at random.
Find the probability that 2 of the 3 are Red.

1. Total number of different choices of 3 from 12 = $ {12 \choose 3} = 220 $
2. Number of ways of choosing 2 Reds from 8 = $ {8 \choose 2} $
3. Number of ways of choosing 1 Blue from 4 = $ {4 \choose 1} $
4. Hence total number of ways of choosing 2 Reds and 1 Blue = $ {8 \choose 2} {4 \choose 1} = 112 $
5. Hence probability of choosing 2 Reds and 1 Blue = $ \frac {{8 \choose 2} {4 \choose 1}}{12 \choose 3} = \frac {112}{220} $